# Element not accesible in jQuery after $.load(content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery with the `$.load()` function to include markup (from separate file) in my main html file, `index.html`

For example, I load `contact.html` in:

```
<div id="bloc_load"></div> in 'index.html'
```

That works correctly.

The issue is, in `contact.html` I have:

```
<input type="button" id="button_of_contact">
```

This element is loaded in `index.html` but I cannot access it with:

```
$('#button_of_contact').click(function(){
    alert('Click');
});
```

If I view the source code in `index.html` after loading `contact.html`, I see:

```
<div id="bloc_load"></div>
```

The `div` is empty, so I think jQuery cannot access. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Thank you :) Seems to be a famous web community !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the content is loaded :

```
$("#bloc_load").on('click', '#button_of_contact', function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

You will have to check the console to see the altered code with the loaded content, just right clicking and view source won't show the added content.

Answer (score 2):

#### Description

You need jQuery `.live()` or `.on()` method to bind events to dynamically created html.

Choose `.live()` or `.on()` depending on the version of jQuery you are using.

> **.live()** Available since jQuery 1.3. Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
>
> **.on()** Available since jQuery 1.7. Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Check out my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3MR43/5/)

#### Sample

**... for jQuery.live()**

```
$('#button_of_contact').live("click", function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();  
    // do something;        
});
```

**... for jQuery.on()**

```
$('#button_of_contact').on("click", function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();  
    // do something;       
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3MR43/5/)
- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

### Update

> **jQuery Docs - As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method.**

#### Sample

```
$("#button_of_contact").delegate("input", "click", function() {
    e.preventDefault();  
    // do something; 
});
```

Comment: According to the docs (to which you link) `delegate()` is recommended over using `live()`: "As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`."

Comment: Thanks a lot too ! It's working fine now, you give me the same good solution with adeneo. And many thanks for the explaination!

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong. The example with `on()` is not delegated, and is exactly the same as using `click()`. Otherwise it's very nicely laid out.